# Understanding NumPy dtype "c" with strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, char

**Goal:** Convert `str` to `np.ndarray` of `bytes` of size 1:

```
import numpy as np
np.array("abc", dtype=[whatever])
```

Actual result without dtype: `array('abc', dtype='<U3')`

Desired result: `array([b'a', b'b', b'c'], dtype=[whatever]` This lets me use slicing to get

**Workaround I found but don't understand:**

```
np.array("abc", dtype='c')
# array([b'a', b'b', b'c'], dtype='|S1')
```

I found this by trial and error, thinking that `'c'` could mean 'char'

**What I don't understand:**
Why is `dtype='c'` working the way it is? According to [arrays.dtypes reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) the `'c'` is short for "complex-floating point", while `'|S1'` is a "zero-terminated bytes (not recommended)" of length 1.

Also directly using '|S1' as `dtype` ignores every character but the first, which is not what I would expect, but I guess it just takes the `"abc"` as one argument and `b'a'` is what comes out if just a single byte is specified as `dtype`:

```
np.array("abc", dtype='|S1')
# array(b'a', dtype='|S1')
```

**Question(s):**

1. Why is `dtype='c'` working the way it is?
2. (If `dtype='c'` is just working "by accident", what would be a "right way" to do this?)

**PS:**
Yes, there is a [np.chararray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html), but according to the linked documentation:

> The chararray class exists for backwards compatibility with Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from numpy 1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of dtype object_, string_ or unicode_, and use the free functions in the numpy.char module for fast vectorized string operations.

However recommended dtypes `object_`, `string_` and `unicode_` don't split the string into chars but return a `ndarray` with one element.

Comment: 'c' is listed under the `'Array-protocol type strings (see The Array Interface)'` section, where the letter must be followed by a size number, as in `np.dtype('c16')`.  It does not apply to the standalone 'c' string in Python code.  `np.typecodes['Character']` returns 'c'.

Comment: Also compare `np.dtype('c')`, `np.dtype('c8')`, `npdtype('c4')` (error), `np.dtype('S3')`.

Comment: @hpaulj I know that my results from using `'c'` are no complex numbers but bytes-characters. But even if `np.typecodes['Character']` returns `'c'`, `np.array("abc", dtype=np.character)` does not return the same as `np.array("abc", dtype='c')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug to me. Note that if you don't specify the number of bytes after the character code 'c', then the dtype is actually 'S1', not the complex floating-point. Have a look at these attributes for dtypes:

```
>>> dt_S1 = np.dtype('S1')
>>> dt_S1, dt_S1.kind, dt_S1.name, dt_S1.char
(dtype('S1'), 'S', 'bytes8', 'S')

>>> dt_c = np.dtype('c')
>>> dt_c, dt_c.kind, dt_c.name, dt_c.char))
(dtype('S1'), 'S', 'bytes8', 'c')

>>> dt_c8 = np.dtype('c8')
>>> dt_c8, dt_c8.kind, dt_c8.name, dt_c8.char
(dtype('complex64'), 'c', 'complex64', 'F')
```

So one would expect for `np.array('abc', dtype='c')` and `np.array('abc', dtype='S1')` to return the same result `array(b'a', dtype='S1')`, or for the former to give an error as would `np.array('abc', dtype='c8')`.

Imho, the correct way to achieve your task would be:

```
np.array(list('abc'), dtype='S1')
```